# HP ProLiant DL380 G5 BIOS Settings Wont Stay

Tags: hp, bios

Due to a damaged PCI-E interface, the motherboard was replaced on this HP ProLiant DL380 G5.

Every boot the POST reports:

```
System currently defaulted to typical configuration settings
```

Any configuration changes made in the BIOS will be reset to the default due to this. This is preventing the installation of ESXi because "No-Execute Memory Protection" cannot be enabled.

I checked / reset the dip switch for BIOS reset.

I replace BIOS battery for good measure.

I entered the serial / part number in BIOS (which gets reset also).

I re flashed the BIOS with the most current current version.

I ran a full test error free with the HP Service Pack for ProLiant.

Can anyone think of anything I missed or may need to configure for this new motherboard?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd trash the server. The G5 ProLiants are on the wrong side of the compatibility curve and at the point where their value has dropped too far to try to diagnose issues. The going rate for a DL380 G5 is ~$200US. They can be found for far less (chassis down to $30).

Where did you get the new motherboard? If it's from the HP parts depot (through support channels), there's a chance that it's bad. Sometimes HP sends bad parts. For older equipment like this, HP tend to *buy back* components from off-lease returns and other product liquidators.

If you obtained the system board as part of a warranty repair, ask for another. If you bought it on your own, buy another.

The behavior you're describing would point to a problem with the new/replacement system board. Did it ever work without the ugly POST messages?

Comment: Thank you for your assessment of value. System was out of warranty, so part was purchased from a random online retailer.